# Universal Angular2 „WeakMap” not defined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, angular, .net-core

I'm trying to build portal based on [Angular 2 + Universal & ASP.NET Core Advanced Starter](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal)

Unfortunately this solution containt builtin "WeakMap" collection which is [compatibile with IE11+ only](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)

I would like to run my project on IE9+ and my question is if someone made some workaround for this issue. I have read on project GitHub that this issue will be fixed in Angular4 without fixed date.

Implementing ES6-Shim solves most issues [but "WeakMap"](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim#weakmap-shim)

I've started building my project some time ago, however newest solution with Angular 2.4.10 is still affected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the proposed solution in the last comment here: https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/648

Comment: Did it first. Unfortunately no success. (I've imported it directly before `import 'angular2-universal-polyfills';`  in boot-server.ts and boot-tests.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I've found out two different "workarounds"

- Comment whole function which cause IE hang. It seems like standard project doesn't use WeakMap anyway so it fix problem on IE10
- Project doesn't includes meta-equiv. I've added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` to _Layout.cshtml which set default compatibility mode with highest possible IE version.